# Using directories to model content vs databases

Tags: file, design-patterns

The first time I saw this was when I experimented with the Netbeans Framework. If for example you wanted to create a menu on a UI form you would create files whose filenames would correspond to a menu entry.  So for example if you wanted "File", "Edit" and "About" in your menu you would create actual files with those names and place them in a directory.  Maybe that directories name was Menu.  So in other words the content of your application was derived from  directories, their names and structure and the files that sit in them but not necessarily the data in the files.

So fast forward to now...my boss wants me to model a hierarchical relationship between data...my first inclination was to model it using a DB but when he shared with me his design he had conceptualized it by using the presence of files in directories to model the relationships.  At first I was like "this is highly irregular" but then I recalled Netbeans so I couldn't tell him that it was crazy or unusual without being a hypocrite since I had seen it before.

Is there a name for this approach?  I guess my interest in it at this point is purely academic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filesystem is, in essence, a hierarchical database. There are many instances where such an approach is used. Two which stand out at the moment are the Windows Start menu and the Maildir mail storage format.

I do not know if there is an explicit name for this. However, it is a valid approach to solving the storage problem. Of course, you have to take a few things into consideration. 
Will the storage be only hierarchical or will "relationships" need to be stored as well. 
What about the number of objects (files) stored? 
File naming issues? 
Access rights? 
Number of files per directory?

In some cases, a database ends up being simpler. Perhaps something like Active Directory or a document-based database like MongoDB may be better solutions.